# Why did rAmAnuja disobey his guru?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, guru, ramanujacharya, vishishtadvaita, initiation

> Thirukottiyur Nambi agreed to part with the Mantra and its meaning.
> But before that he got a promise from Ramanauja. As per the promise,
> [Ramanuja](http://srivaishnavam.com/ramanuja_lifehistory.htm) should not tell this to anyone as this mantra will take a
> person who listens to it directly to Vaikuntam and if it is told out
> to others Ramanuja **will go to hell**.  Ramanuja with great excitement
> and anxiety got the mantra and started going back to SriRangam.  While
> he was walking thinking of what he heard, all of a sudden he had a
> feeling and wanted this mantra to be known to one and all in the world
> so that everyone can reach Vaikundam.
>
> Thirukottiyur Nambi came to know of this and became very **angry**.

From the above passage its clear that Nambi did wanted him to keep the mantra secret.

It is another matter if later he was convinced or not.

My questions are,

**Is this to be considered to be a guru droham ?**

**If at all ramanuja wanted all to be liberated (which is understood), why he didn't take prior permission for doing so ?**

**What shastras allow one to go against gurus wish and do it without prior permission?**

Comment: No shastras allow it. These things only happen in Kali Yuga. Do u know of many such examples of disciples disobeying their Gurus orders' from scriptures? They just set bad examples.

Comment: @Rickross, I accept that it's not allowed in scripture, but that does't mean they set bad examples in society. Sri Ramanuja did that for welfare of other. he believed that greatest spiritual pursuit should be for the welfare of the whole mankind even at the cost of one’s own life. Same way goes to Great Bali Maharaj's story who is favourite devotee of supreme lord. I believe that Guru Droham is biggest sin, but we should never judge higher spiritual personalities by our own speculation if we are judging then we are also doing bigger sin than them. :)

Comment: @ShreeKrishna there is no harm in judging. Further we should not have spiritual inferiority complex that we are. Very interior etc.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna Apart from that Demon's example which other examples u got that teach us that Guru can be disobeyed?? Can u show even one such examples from our scriptures? A Demon is neither our role model nor his acts our ideals. Rama, Krishna are considered Gods, Now did they ever disobey their Guru? So, it's fair to say that we can expect such things to happen only in Kali.

Comment: @Rickross & Rakesh Joshi, I respect both of your belief and thinking have good spiritual life ahead. :)